# Load PDF from filesystem into an Ionic (Cordova) + Android + pdf.js application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, pdf.js

I have trouble integrating pdf.js into an Android Ionic application. I want pdf.js to render a pdf to a prepared canvas.

The problem occurs when I am trying to load the document using:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(FILE_PATH)
```

which always ends up with an error. I did some research, there are a lot of questions on SO and the internet on loading files to pdf.js but either they discuss loading pdfs from server, not `file://` urls, or they propose some changes in native android code, which I would like to avoid: if possible I am looking for a pure JS cordova solution, or a plugin.

I tried experimenting with `PDFJS.disableWorker`. Setting this to false results in `cannot read property 'length' of null`, setting to true results in errors while loading the file that `xhr` request couldn't load the file.

I should have all the necessary read permission set in the configuration file.

My question is, if anyone successfully loaded a local (`file://..`) pdf into a cordova application using pdf.js, preferably using JS or a plugin, because I would like to expand to other platforms, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: You mostly looking for an answer for "can I load file:// resource using XMLHttpRequest into a cordova application?"-question -- the PDF.js is using XHR to load PDF data.

Comment: Well, pdf.js is doing this loading internally. If there is some switch to make it use something else then XHR, or apply some permissions to allow it, I am all for such solution, but I didn't find anything yet

Comment: pdf.js has alternative way to deliver PDF data -- via Uint8Array or other array like things. Uint8Array can be passed as is to the getDocument, other things shall be wrapped getDocument({data: binaryData});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user async5 pointed out, `PDFJS.getDocument()` accepts input in 3 different formats. Apart from URL, it also accepts `Uint8Array` data. So two more steps are needed to get file in desired format, first is to load the file as array buffer and the second is to convert it to Uint8Array. Following is working, pure JS example for Ionic, using Cordova File plugin:

```
$cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(DIRECTORY_URL, FILENAME).then(function(arraybuffer) { //DIRECTORY_URL starts with file://
  var uInt8Arr = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  PDFJS.getDocument(uInt8Arr).then(function(pdf) {
      //do whatever you want with the pdf, for example render it using 'pdf.getPage(page) and page.render() functions
  }, function (error) {
      console.log("PDFjs error:" + error.message);
  });
}, function(error){
  console.log("Load array buffer error:" + error.message);
});
```

this is an Cordova example, without using Ionic

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FILE_URL, function(e){
    e.file(function(f){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            PDFJS.getDocument(new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)).then(function(pdf) {
                //do whatever you want with the pdf, for example render it using 'pdf.getPage(page) and page.render() functions
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("PDFjs error:" + error.message);
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    });
}, function(e){
    console.log("error getting file");
});
```