# How to display PDF files in Cordova application for Android?

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, pdfviewer

I am developing an Android application using Cordova where I am required to display a PDF file in application.
I have tried using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) from Mozilla and it worked only on browser and not in application. Same was the case with `<embed></embed>`.

I am not able to find any solution, please help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022359/load-pdf-from-filesystem-into-an-ionic-cordova-android-pdf-js-application ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant Open PDF in cordova webview. Try Phonegap [File Opener](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) Plugin.

Comment: Will this plugin open PDF in application? or exit application and open with PDF viewer application like Google PDF viewer application. My requirement is to have in-app PDF Viewer

Comment: its like "Open With" option of windows.. :)

Comment: you cant open pdf file in cordova web browser

Comment: Try `window.open(pdf-url, '_system', '');` This will open PDF in system browser.

Comment: > Due to signficant changes in the way that Android handles permissions from version 11 onwards, this plugin does not work with Android 11 or later and would require significant changes to make this happen.