# How to implement a piece of code within a hyperlink?

Tags: android, cordova, pdf.js

I have often seen peices of codes such as this one:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FILE_URL, function(e){
    e.file(function(f){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            PDFJS.getDocument(new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)).then(function(pdf) {
                //do whatever you want with the pdf, for example render it using 'pdf.getPage(page) and page.render() functions
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("PDFjs error:" + error.message);
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    });
}, function(e){
    console.log("error getting file");
});
```

and I am not sure how to implment it wihtin my html. 
Would it be like this:

```
<a href=" ../res/DOC140416-1.pdf" onclick=window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FILE_URL, function(e){
    e.file(function(f){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            PDFJS.getDocument(new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)).then(function(pdf) {
                'pdf.getPage(page) 
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("PDFjs error:" + error.message);
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    });
}, function(e){
    console.log("error getting file");
}); >  
link to my pdf 2</a>
```

If not hos should it be done?
This piece of code was got from [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022359/load-pdf-from-filesystem-into-an-ionic-cordova-android-pdf-js-application)
Thanks!

Comment: In your onclick code, you can call a new function and paste the script code which you mentioned in the first section inside the new function. In the code you mentioned in your second section, after onclick=, double quote is missing. It should be onclick="some business logic"

Comment: Thanks Gandhi. Do you think this code is worth anything to open a pdf file?

Comment: I don't have hands on experience in pdfjs. You mat have to check in original post. But can help you out if you post errors if any

Comment: There are no errors. It just leads nowhere. I referenced the pdf libraries:

Comment: There are no errors. It just leads nowhere. I referenced the pdf libraries:   <script type="text/Javascript" src="../js/pdf.js"></script>
   <script type="text/Javascript" src="../js/pdf.worker.js"></script>     Then I referenced the file that contains the function:  'code' <script type="text/Javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>    In the index.js there is this funciton:    function readassets()
HERE IS THE EXACT SNIPNET I PASTED IN THE QUESSTION

Then I wrote this HTML link:     <a href=" ../res/DOC140416-1.pdf" onclick="readassets()"; >  
link to my pdf with pdf.js</a>